# How can I automate hard line breaks every X characters?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2011

I'd like to hard-code line breaks into a Word doc (interview transcript) every X (e.g, 72) characters, split at spaces. I'd like to preserve rich text formatting. What's the easiest way to do this? If a Word macro, what would it be? I found some [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b79dc44-f619-454f-8586-734b7f529ada/a-macro-that-splits-lines-after-80-characters?forum=isvvba) but they throw all kinds of errors for me. I'm running Word 2011 with MVB 14.4.9.

Comment: Notepad++ can wrap text at any number of characters (or unwrap, too). Cut and paste into and from Notepad++. Note that this loses all formatting, though.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Notepad++ is available for OS X?

Comment: Oops.. probably not (unless you've also installed Windows), but there are a slew of similar text editors for Mac OS: see http://alternativeto.net/software/notepad-plus-plus/?platform=mac